# Setting up Windows network on Xen

Tags: linux, windows, networking, xen

I'm trying to install a Windows XP server in a Xen environment. The OS is booting fine. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to set up the network settings.

Dom0 is a Debian Lenny currently hosting around 10 Linux virtual servers.

Windows tells me I have a "limited connection". It can't get any DHCP response, nor access other hosts in the network

Here is the Xen's client config file:

```
kernel = '/usr/lib/xen-3.2-1/boot/hvmloader'
builder = 'hvm'
memory = '1024'
device_model='/usr/lib/xen-3.2-1/bin/qemu-dm'
acpi=1
apic=1
pae=1
vcpus=1
name = 'winexchange'
# Disks
disk = [
        'phy:/dev/wnghosts/exchange-disk,ioemu:hda,w',
        'file:/mnt/freespace/ISO/DVD1_Installation.iso,ioemu:hdc:cdrom,r'
]
# Networking
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3E:0A:D0:1B, type=ioemu, bridge=xenbr0']
# video
stdvga=0
serial='pty'
ne2000=0
# Behaviour
boot='c'
sdl=0
# VNC
vfb = [ 'type=vnc' ]
vnc=1
vncdisplay=1
vncunused=1
usbdevice='tablet'
```

- Server config (/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp)

```
(network-script network-bridge)
(vif-script vif-bridge)
(dom0-min-mem 512)
(dom0-cpus 0)
(vnc-listen '0.0.0.0')
```

ifconfig (cleaned up):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:c7:90:34
          inet addr:10.20.10.9  Bcast:10.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::230:48ff:fec7:9034/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9124214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5560279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1501725024 (1.3 GiB)  TX bytes:3721460671 (3.4 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8700 (8.4 KiB)  TX bytes:8700 (8.4 KiB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:c7:90:34
          inet6 addr: fe80::230:48ff:fec7:9034/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2574257469 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:1798883882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2351005981 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:3255923331 (3.0 GiB)
          Memory:de220000-de240000

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:ff:e8:e4:b1:43
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ff:e8ff:fee4:b143/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:8205 (8.0 KiB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

vif116.0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:1854 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The xm-network list command gave me an unusual output:

```
# xm network-list winxp01
Idx BE     MAC Addr.     handle state evt-ch tx-/rx-ring-ref BE-path
0   0  00:16:3E:0A:D0:1C    0     1      -1    -1   /-1      /local/domain/0/backend/vif/116/0
```

What do these elements stand for? "state evt-ch tx-/rx-ring-ref"

What did I do wrong?
Please tell me if you want some more info (logs, etc)

Comment: If you use a static IP for you WinXP does it work ? Have you got other HVM domains working ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. Static IP for my XP does not work either.
I've got currently 12 Linux domU's running on this server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found after three weeks of searching.

Had to download some "Xen" network driver here: http://www.meadowcourt.org/downloads/

Pfew... glad it's resolved.

Comment: Where did you find the answer? Which driver did you download? Are there instructions somewhere? Did you set up all the gplpv features, or just networking?

Comment: I don't remember which one I picked up, maybe  gplpv_XP_0.11.0.238.msi. I found the link here: http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenWindowsGplPv